# Can't insert a calendar to a user using service account

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have a service account setting up with wide domain delegation.
The domain contains about 300 accounts.

For each account, I want to create it own calendar called `New_UserName_EDT` other than the main calendar (called `userName`).
And for each `New_UserName_EDT`'s user, I want to create an event **depending** on the user.

If it's possible, could you please tell me how can I add a calendar to a specific user under a domain using the service account ?.

If not, can I share the calendar `New_UserName_EDT` created with service account with event `event1` (attendee is `user1`) with the user `user1`, without selecting the `New_UserName_EDT`and then on `Settings and sharing > Share with specific people` section,  click on `Add people` and add `user1` [as described here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4RQN.png) ?.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add required scope:

```
        AclRule rule = new AclRule();
        Scope scope = new Scope();
        scope.setType("user").setValue("userName@domain");
        rule.setScope(scope).setRole("reader");

        // Insert new access rule
        AclRule createdRule = service.acl().insert(createdCalendar.getId(), rule).execute();
```

HTH